# Vue.js vue-router не возвращает страницу с компонентом

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

Использую Vue.js и vue-router. Проблема заключается в том, что при нажатии на кнопку с параметром to="login" url меняется на "http://localhost:8080/#/login" однако компонент не возвращается, а остается прежний и в консоль не выводится никаких ошибок. Т.е. внешний вид страницы не изменяется. В чем может быть проблема?
В работе создано два компонента App.vue и login.vue. Переход осуществляется с html страницы, её код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Игра Брейн-ринг</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    </div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
    <router-view></router-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Работает все через main.js:

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
    import App from './App.vue';
    import Login from './login.vue';
    Vue.use(VueRouter);
    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            {
                path: "#",
                component: App
            },
            {
                path: "/login",
                component: Login
            }
      ]
    });
    const app = new Vue({
        router,
        render: function (createElement) {
            return createElement(App);
        }
    }).$mount('#app');
```

И код двух компонентов.
Компонент app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/brain.png">
    <h1></h1>
    <h2>Правила игры Брейн-ринг</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Игра начинается с...</li>
      <li>Вам нужно успеть дать правильный ответ первее...</li>
      <li>Время на ответ 30 секунд...</li>
      <li>Игра Брейн-ринг заканчивается...</li>
      </ul>
    <h2>Вперед!</h2>
    <router-link to="/login">
<div class="wrapper">
    <button v-on:click="onClick" id="submit-button"><b>Начать игру</b></button>
</div></router-link>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {
                msg: 'Добро пожаловать в игру Брейн-ринг'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            onClick: function() {
                console.log('');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

И компонент login.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="login">
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'login',
        data() {
            return {
                msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
            }
        }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

Для создания проекта использовал CLI-шаблон webpack-simple.

Comment: а что это за путь такой /#/login
т.е. не кажется ли вам, что нужно убрать слэш перед login, или из пути #

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Со структурой у вас беда какая-то - `id="app"` и в основном файле и в компоненте. `<router-view>` должен быть внутри `<div id='app'></div>` основного файла.
В роутере имхо нужно убрать #:

```
routes: [
    {
        path: "",
        component: App
    },
    {
        path: "/login",
        component: Login
    }
]
```

Comment: Не знал просто о правилах структуры, поэтому наворотил лишнего, изменения помогли, это работает)

Answer (score 1):

Перемести router-view в App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <!--  твой код    -->
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Добавил `<router-view></router-view>` в app.vue теперь он при нажатии возвращает и компонент app.vue и компонент login.vue т.е. остается все с компонента app и внизу появляется надпись "регистрация" с компонента login.vue

Answer (score 1):

```
routes: [
    {
        path: "/",
        component: App
    },
    {
        path: "/login",
        component: Login
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно `<router-view></router-view>` надо переместить внуть `<div id='app'></div>`, или даже в компонент app.vue

Comment: Добавил `<router-view></router-view>` в app.vue теперь он при нажатии возвращает и компонент app.vue и компонент login.vue т.е. остается все с компонента app и внизу появляется надпись "регистрация" с компонента login.vue

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема решилась. Не знаю, в чем именно она заключалась, но вот рабочий код. 
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Игра Брейн-ринг</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view></router-view>

    </div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './App.vue';
import Login from './login.vue';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: Login
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            component: App
        }
  ]
});
new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img src="./assets/brain.png">
    <h2>Правила игры Брейн-ринг</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>Игра начинается с...</li>
      <li>Вам нужно успеть дать правильный ответ первее...</li>
      <li>Время на ответ 30 секунд...</li>
      <li>Игра Брейн-ринг заканчивается...</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Вперед!</h2>
    <router-link to="/login">
        <div class="wrapper">
        <button v-on:click="onClick" id="submit-button"><b>Начать игру</b></button>
        </div>
    </router-link>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {
                msg: 'Добро пожаловать в игру Брейн-ринг'
            }

        },
        methods: {
            onClick: function() {
                console.log('');
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

login.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>Регистрация</h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'login',
        data() {
            return {
                msg: 'Регистрация'
            }

        }
    }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```